# How to share a binary file with Delphi on Android?

Tags: android, delphi

I need to share a binary file (an SQLite database, in fact) from a Delphi 10.4 app on Android 11. The code looks like this:

```
var    
  Database : String;  

Database := TPath.Combine(ExternalPath, 'file.db');  // permission is granted  
intent := TJIntent.Create;   
intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);   
intent.setType(StringToJString('*/*')); 
intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString('Important data'));

if (TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT < 24) Then // this is for Android 10    
  fileuri := JParcelable(TJNet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(Database))))  
else   
  fileuri := JParcelable(TJNet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(Database)));

intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM, fileuri);
```

`Database` is received in the Shared documents directory/myapp via WiFi. Later when the `intent` is used:

```
SharedActivity.startActivity(TJIntent.JavaClass.createChooser(intent, StrToJCharSequence('Share with')));
```

The dialog appears, I select the app (Telegram, Whatsapp, Mail) but nothing is sent. Whatsapp does nothing, and Mail sends the content without the attachment.

Maybe the other apps do not have access to the shared directory (it ran fine with Android 10). It is created the very first time the app is run. It was placed there so it would be easy to find with a file manager.

Should I store the file in another directory? Am I missing something? Before sharing, I close the file so the shared one can open it since AFAIK SQLite locks the file.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Android, when sending a file URI, you need to grant permission to the receiving app to access the file that the URI refers to.

Per [Sending simple data to other apps | Sending binary content](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#send-binary-content):

> The receiving application needs permission to access the data the Uri points to. The recommended ways to do this are:
>
> - Store the data in your own [`ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider), making sure that other apps have the correct permission to access your provider. The preferred mechanism for providing access is to use [per-URI permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions#uri) which are temporary and only grant access to the receiving application. An easy way to create a [`ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider) like this is to use the [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) helper class.
> - Use the system [`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore). The [`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) is primarily for video, audio and image MIME types, however beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11) it can also store non-media types (see [`MediaStore.Files`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files) for more info). Files can be inserted into the [`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) using [`scanFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener)) after which a `content://` style [`Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri) suitable for sharing is passed to the provided [`onScanCompleted()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener#onScanCompleted(java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri)) callback. Note that once added to the system [`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) the content is accessible to any app on the device.

Per [Give access on a per-URI basis](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/restrict-interactions#uri):

> You can also grant permissions on a per-URI basis. When starting an activity or returning a result to an activity, set the [`Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) intent flag, the [`Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION) intent flag, or both flags. This gives other apps read, write, or read/write permissions, respectively, for the data URI that's included in the intent. Other apps gain these permissions for the specific URI regardless of whether they have permission to access data in the content provider more generally.
>
> For example, suppose that a user is using your app to view an email with an image attachment. Other apps shouldn't be able to access the email contents in general, but they might be interested in viewing the image. Your app can use an intent and the `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` intent flag to let an image-viewing app see the image.

Try adding a call to `addFlags()` to your `Intent`s, eg:

```
intent.addFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
...
TJIntent.JavaClass.createChooser(intent,...).addFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

Comment: I followed your instructions Remy but got the same result. Your answer pointed me in the right direction. Searching here at SO and looking your "Give access on a per-URI basis" it prompts something about content and file providers and enabling "Secure file sharing" Also a fileprovider.xml is mentioned. I am missing something? Thank you for your help. I'm a Delphi old wolf but an Android breast feeding baby